# Overriding VB Code using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, vb.net

I had a problem with a vb.net webpage which I solved by commenting out a .Focus() in the page_load. The customer however, will not receive this amendment until next release.

My question is, is it possible to achieve the same result using jquery through an external js file. ie. I would like to know if I can 'bypass' the '.Focus()' line in the page_load by using some kind of jquery wizardry?

I'm guessing that the answer will be 'no', however I'm still hopeful! :-)

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the id of the control (or name) you can set focus to it by calling:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#elementId').focus();
    // or
    // $('input[name="elementName"]').focus();
}
```

This will change WHAT is focused, not un-setting focus

If you know the ID of the focused element you can do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#elementId').blur();
    // or
    // $('input[name="elementName"]').blur();
}
```

to un-focus it.

you could also do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input').blur();
}
```

if you just wanna unset the focus from all/any input

And in my tests this will override asp.net's attempt to set focus (read: asp.net will focus one thing, your script will afterwards focus another thing, so there might be a race for control here, but at least on my page (asp.net c#) and in chrome this works so that the jquery.focus runs last, thus wins :))

**Edit/Update:**
Should the problem that the control receives focus rather then having focus, you can overwrite the auto_focus function that asp.net uses when you call .Focus() in your code-behind.

For me this works:

```
WebForm_AutoFocus = function () { };
```

However this might cause other things to not work (I do not know if this javascript function is used for other things besides setting the .Focus() from your codebehind, but it might be worth trying.)
You should also set this somewhere "late" in your code, eg: after WebForm_AutoFocus is rendered to your page by the asp.net runtime, and where this is done i do not know.

Comment: I might have been to quick with my answer, using blur will not stop the control from receiving focus, it will only un-set it. (I took for granted that the problem came from the control having input, not getting the input, if getting the input is the problem then you might have a bit of a problem, what you could do then is to try and overwrite asp.net's javascript autofocus function,.. this might however affect other things (that i do not know of)... :P i will look into this and update my answer accordingly regards of this is an issue for you :P

Comment: I have edited to post to show you how you can try to disable the autofocus feature by overriding what that particular javascript function does, however you will have to try if this works for you (It did for me anyways)